# java.lang.VerifyError when initialising aspects

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am trying to weave some methods with an aspect using aspectj at load time.

My aspect is

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(MyAnnotation) && execution(* com.sample.dao..*(..))")
    public Object doProfile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
         System.out.println("inside aspect)";
         return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

The method which is going to be woven is a DAO and already annotated with Spring @Repository

```
@Repository
public class BoxDAO extends BaseDAO{
    @MyAnnotation
    public void saveBox(Entity e){  
         super.saveEntity(e);   
    }
}
```

When I m running a test class to test the above configuration, I am getting the below error. ( From the logs I can see that weaving takes place at the methods (by using -showWeaveInfo).

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 7
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sample/aspect/MyAspect.<clinit>()V @1: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 00b8 007a a700 084b 2ab3 0073 b1       
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [1, 7] => handler: 7

    at com.sample.dao.BoxDAO.saveBox(BoxDAO.java:39)
    at com.sample.BoxService.saveBox(BoxService.java:71)
    at com.sample.service.BoxService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1c74bbc6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.sample.service.BoxService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ee501a7.saveBox(<generated>)
    at com.sample.BoxServiceTest.saveBoxTest(BoxServiceTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Please note I m using aspectjweaver-1.8.9 as weaving agent and run time is jdk 1.8. 
Is there any limitation that aspectj cannot weave Spring proxies or is there anything wrong with my configuration. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple versions of aspectj in my class path and that was causing the above error. Once removing the older version, it started working.